# Cancelling golang os.Stdin read using context

Tags: linux, macos, go

I want to be able to cancel an os.Stdin read using context which is not possible. Usually, you close the file handle to accomplish cancel, but I do not want to close os.Stdin

Possible solutions could be:

- Can it be determined if Stdin.Read will block?
- Can the thread be terminated like in pthreads?
- Should os.Stdin be forwarded to another file handle that can be closed?

Here’s what I got, the ugliness is that scannerThread is left running on context cancelation:

```
// Keystrokes emits keystroke events
// on g0.Context() shutdown, scannerThread is left running until the next newline
// the lines channel is never closed
func Keystrokes(lines chan<- string, g0 parl.Go) {
  var err error
  defer g0.Done(err)
  defer parl.Recover(parl.Annotation(), &err, parl.NoOnError)

  // stdio.Scan cannot be terminated, so let that thread terminate whenever
  var scanLines parl.NBChan[string]
  go scannerThread(scanLines.Send, g0.Context())

  // consume scannerThread output
  scannerCh := scanLines.Ch()
  done := g0.Context().Done()
  for {
    select {
    case line := <-scannerCh:
      lines <- line
    case <-done:
      return // canceled by context exit
    }
  }
}

// scannerThread reads from os.Stdin and therefore cannot be cancelled.
// send is a non-blocking send function.
// ctx indicates shutdown effective on next os.Stdin newline.
func scannerThread(send func(string), ctx context.Context) {
  var err error
  defer parl.Recover(parl.Annotation(), &err, parl.Infallible)

  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
  for scanner.Scan() { // scanner is typically stuck here
    if ctx.Err() != nil {
      return // terminated via context
    }
    send(scanner.Text())
  }

  // scanner had error
  err = scanner.Err()
}
```

Comment: You cannot reliably cancel a read on stdin, even by closing the FD (this is the same as in pthreads, which are used by goroutines, which is why you can't do it)

Comment: The standard way of dealing with this is just to start a "stdin reader" goroutine at the start of your program, and have that communicate input over a channel or channels, which are more flexible.   Leave it alive and running its r/w loop infinitely through the whole program - it's just a single goroutine which never spins.

Comment: The answer is to use non-blocking read: err = unix.SetNonblock(int(os.Stdin.Fd()), true). It does not produce input any sooner, but the thread will not block and can react immediately to context cancelation

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to read os.Stdin non-blocking, works on Linux macOS

os.Stdin has a block against closing it, I remember

Non-blocking os.Stdin.Read() returns bytes once a complete line is available, otherwise returns n==0

Here is how to set non-blocking:

```
err = unix.SetNonblock(int(os.Stdin.Fd()), true)
```

The state of non-blocking can also be read:

```
flags, err := unix.FcntlInt(os.Stdin.Fd(), unix.F_GETFL, 0)
wasSet = flags&unix.O_NONBLOCK != 0
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this out of the box. You need to rely on special implementation that leverage the OS capabilities.

There is a library that can just do that apparently:
https://github.com/muesli/cancelreader

Here is how it works:

```golang
r, err := cancelreader.NewReader(file)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
    ...
}

// cancel after five seconds
go func() {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    r.Cancel()
}()

// keep reading
for {
    var buf [1024]byte
    _, err := r.Read(buf[:])

    if errors.Is(err, cancelreader.ErrCanceled) {
        fmt.Println("canceled!")
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        // handle other errors
        ...
    }

    // handle data
    ...
}
```

It does everything you are looking for, in a relatively cross-platform manner.